# Inner product of continuous functions

Tags: inner-products

I'm sure i'm missing something but i've come to this definition of inner product:

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$$

For functions $F:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Now, I know that there are periodic functions whose integral is $0$ while the function iteself is not $0$ everywhere. How do we know there is not such a function, non nul, such that

$$ \int_a^b f(x)f(x) \ dx = 0$$

and thus invalidating one of the axioms of inner product?

Comment: $f(x)f(x)=f(x)^2$ is always nonnegative.  The only way for the integral of a nonnegative function to be $0$ is if it is zero except on a measure zero subset.  To avoid this, we usually say that two functions are equivalent if they agree except perhaps on a measure zero subset.  Also, if you are only considering continuous functions, this will never happen because a continuous function which is nonzero at a point is nonzero in a neighborhood of a point.  Let me know if you'd like a more detailed answer instead of a list of facts.

Comment: Somehow I completely forgot about the tiny detail that a square is always positive :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you square the function when you multiply it with itself. No square is negative, so the integral is positive definite, just like the inner product. The only case where the integral evaluates to 0 is if all values are 0 on the interval of interest, and therefore it is the 0 vector function

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the indicator function of the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$, then $f\neq0$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)f(x)dx=0$